# Sharing object between multiple EAR apps

Tags: jakarta-ee

Is there a way to share objects between multiple EAR apps deployed on the same machine?

We have multiple core services which acts as a microservices. Its not strict ms architecture but anyway each service is deployed as a separate EAR. The request flow (use case) requires to hit many applications (EAR) to complete the process. How can i pass my "User data object" between different ejb apps?

@ApplicationScoped CDI context is visible only within one EAR...

Is there something like app container shared memory which can be used for that?

Answer (score 1):

many ways to tackle this.  it all depends on how familiar you are with EE and how big/small your session payload is.  from a tacit view point (without much detail of your project) you can:

- put the session into a map that is registered into JNDI.  each service can then lookup the map and obtain the session object using some hash/key.
- put the session(s) into a stateful session bean (shopping cart model) that expose a Remote interface that the services can then bind to.
- explore the proprietary features of your EE container.  some containers (jboss, websphere, maybe others) provide facilities for deployments to share authenticated user sessions (basically poor-man's SSO).

these are the most obvious solutions i can think of that do not break the EE standards.  i'm sure there are other more exotic or third-party solutions that can be leveraged.

caveat emptor

Answer (score 0):

Memory between all application that are deployed in one app server is shared(there is on vm) but  each application has different class loader so if you get(by JNDI lookup or other mechanism) a object that is created by another ear you will get classcastexception

calling service between different ear is always remote( call  by value ) and sharing object between different ear is **impossible** unless put the class in **system lib**(the parent class loader of application class loader)

for more information pls see the below link( it describes class loading in weblogic but the base concepts are the same in different application servers)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs100/programming/classloading.html